# JavaScript, change the href attribute of multiple a elements that have the same class

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change (or control...) my `<a>` href with JavaScript. Here is my HTML structure:

```
<a class="google" href="#">LINK ONE</a>
<a class="google" href="#">LINK TWO</a>
```

And here my JavaScript code:

```
document.querySelectorAll("a.google").href = "https://google.com"
```

If I use `querySelector(".google")` it change the link, but just one of theme. If I use `querySelectorAll(".google")` or `("a.google")` it doesn't change anything.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: actually `document.querySelectorAl` returns an array of elements, you should use an iteration like `for` to access each element then change the `href`

Comment: Read the docs: [`querySelector`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), [`querySelectorAll`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). Please try using the [debugging capabilities](//ali-dev.medium.com/how-to-easily-debug-in-javascript-5bac70f94f1a) of your browser. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and look at what `document.querySelector("a.google")` and `document.querySelectorAll("a.google")` are. [“Can someone help me?” is not an actual question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/4642212).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.querySelectorAll` returns an array of elements. For this to work, and it was a good idea to think about it, you can do like so :

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll("a.google");
links.forEach(link => link.href = "https://google.com");
```